# How can I upgrade wires?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I just completed the research for the conductive wire and I would like to upgrade some parts of my circuit to be able to carry a bigger power load.

In sandbox mode I tried to simply build the conductive wire where there is already a regular wire, but nothing happened.

Is there something I dont understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After jumping back in the game, I figured out that I just need to place the blueprint of the conductive wire where the regular wire is.

It won't exactly upgrade the wire, but once the construction is complete, the old wire will be automatically removed and its resources dropped on the ground. This will be done without cutting the circuit.

The same thing works when upgrading tiles to insulated tiles. I guess it also work for other types of tile.

Comment: Yeah, you just put new wire over the old. It works differently for different things, and sometimes the default priority can be 5 instead of what you set it to.  Which is annoying.